# Show that can't exists a function like that

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, entire-functions

I'm doing this exercise, but I don't know if my solution is good.

> Show that can't exists any entire function $f$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=|\frac{1}{n}|^3$, $ n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus 0$.

I started writing $t=\frac{1}{n}$. So $f(t)=|t|^3$. Since $0$ is an accumulation point for {$z \in \mathbb{C}: f(z)=0$}, then $f$ must be $f=0$. But that's not possible, since $f(t)$ is different from zero for every $t$ in its domain.

Comment: Do you mean to say "continuous" function?

Comment: @Jaideep: It's an odd (but common and standard) term from complex analysis. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)

Comment: @JaideepKhare "Entire" is synonymous with "analytic" or "holomorphic" in complex analysis.

Comment: @Arthur Got it. I haven't studied about complex analysis, that's why I didn't know.

Comment: @Arthur BTW, $\frac{1}{x-1}$ is continuous on its "maximal domain". But not on real line, which is by default our perspective to see continuity.

Comment: @JaideepKhare It's not defined on the whole real line, and therefore cannot be considered as a function there. It can't be discontinuous where it isn't defined. There is a reason the maximal domain is called "maximal". But this is tangential to the actual question here.

Comment: @Arthur But there must be a reason we defined "missing point discontinuity."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If such a function $f$ existed, let $g(z)=z^3$. Then$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f\left(\frac1n\right)=g\left(\frac1n\right).$$Therefore, by the identity theorem, $f=g$. But $f(-1)=1$, whereas $g(-1)=-1$.

One problem with your approach lies in the fact that you tried to apply the identity theorem to a non-analytic function.

Comment: clear now! Thanks